# Reproducing pdfLaTeX formatting in LuaLaTeX

Tags: formatting

I'm having trouble reproducing pdfLaTeX smallcaps, (math/text) bold, and math operators. Here's what it looks like in pdfLaTeX:
[image]

That's how I want LuaLaTeX to look. Instead, I get:
[image: LuaLaTeX rendering]

The main and sans fonts otherwise look fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex 
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
    \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros} 
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{microtype} 
\fi

\begin{document}

\textsc{Test} $\mathbf{r}$ \textbf{m} $\max$

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`, then fontspec won't touch the math fonts. But the text fonts are different, and there is nothing sensible you can do about it: one of the main point of lualatex is that it uses different fonts.

Comment: Thanks - that solves part of the problem! Is there any reasonable workaround for the smallcaps, at least? I've seen that you can specify `SmallCapsFont` as an option to `setmainfont`. 

The main issue is that lualatex-smallcaps will italicize in eg theorem statement environments, which I don't want.

Comment: @JamesComey - Please see the answer I just posted. The `ptm` font family is (a) really old and (b) uses unusually large small-caps. I recommend you load the `newtxtext` package, as its small-caps are of a more standard, i.e., smaller, size.

Comment: what is your problem with the small caps? Imho the pdflatex ones are faked small caps, and so rather suboptimal.

Comment: The problem wasn't actually very related to this one. The problem was that certain small caps weren't staying upright in certain environments. I solved this by writing e.g. `\text{\upshape\textsc{Power}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to replace

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
```

with

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{helvet}
```

and change `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}` to `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchLowercase]`, you'll get a much better correspondence between the outputs of pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Here's the output of compiling the test document shown below with pdfLaTeX:

[image]

And here's the corresponding LuaLaTeX output:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex} % iftex combines the conditionals of ifluatex, ifxetex, and ifpdftex packages
\ifluatex 
    \usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
    \setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\else
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
    %\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
    \usepackage{newtxtext}
    \usepackage[scaled=0.88]{helvet}
\fi
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\textsc{Test} \textbf{mno} \textsf{Hello} $\mathbf{r}$ $\max$ $\det$
\end{document}
```